# Template for dev and sandbox environment in Azure VM

Tags: azure, testing, sandbox

Have not found this yet, so the answer is probably obvious? I'm looking for the quickest way to setup a development sandbox environment on Azure (or elsewhere, for that matter). I prefer this approach to setting up VMs on my own (fixed size) machines. However, I'd like a template approach so I don't have to install everything myself each time (basic Microsoft Visual Studio, DBs, SDKs) and then I can install the CTPs or preview code on top.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to setup the test environment on Azure is to make a custom VHD in which you can install all your Development Softwares just once and upload it to Azure. Then create a VM using that custom VHD and you're good to go.
This can help you on how to create a custom VHD and upload it to Azure [Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/erezs_iis_blog/archive/2013/05/22/uploading-a-custom-operating-system-to-azure-virtual-machines.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I also notice that there are templates available for diverse Visual Studio configuration via the azure gallery...